# I am told my work is 'excellent', but it never makes into a final product. How can I claim my results, if my work is never monetized?

Tags: career-development, salary, performance-reviews

I work for a software company. I have been on a project for nine months, and I have always been reassured by my first-line manager of the fact that my software increments would have been integrated into the system on a regular basis.

Unfortunately, this hasn't been the case: the company is only able to react to customer bugs and feature requests but does not really plan, nor forecast. As we are always in a "state of emergency", there is no time to integrate and regression test my increments.

I have asked whether the problem was with my work, and they were searching for excuses not to deliver it to the customer, but I was told I am an "excellent software engineer", that "my work is valuable", that I am the only one making unit tests (I do this to convince people that my software is stable and robust to corner cases) and other cheerful commendations.

But at the end of the day, middle management and HR are not aware of what I have done and until it makes into a final product, **I cannot claim my results**, for excellent they *might* be.

I have *no time to lose*, a family to take care of, and my salary/title will be reviewed in three months. People that have only fixed bugs and hacked up poor quality software deliverables are more likely to get a pay rise or a promotion, because their work "brought money to the company".

How can I increase my 'visibility' and cause my work to make it into the final product?

Comment: Ouch. I found myself in this same position, and ended up quitting after just 2 months. 9 months of no production work would have driven me insane.

Comment: You make me think that maybe I already made enough mistakes. Any last resort before quitting? Did you try anything that didn't work for you, but could work for me?

Comment: TBH it was more about my personality. I felt *very* under-appreciated at that company, so what happened with me is likely different than what's going on with you.

Comment: I understand, but being told that I am "awesome" and then left alone with no schedule and no results to present is appalling as well. Let's wait for answer. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @swdev Your question is getting flagged as off-topic because it asks 'what to do'. I have taken the liberty to change your end questions. You can [edit] it further or revert my edit.

Comment: I think you have two options (which don't answer your question, thus a comment) - Try to change the company culture (long term commitment; e.g. get the whole team TDDing) or move. I recommend the later.

Comment: The bright side is that it's nicer to implement new features than just fixing bugs. So although you can't show them to your managers, you learn possible more this way.

Comment: The current ridiculous fashion is to believe that the only "results" which matter are ones which are expressible in some kind of simple statement with quantifiable measurements and that these must be achieved in a crisply defined interval of time (eg "increased revenue by X% in previous quarter"). The reality is that it is NEVER that simple. Savvy managers understand that, regardless of what HR-drones instruct you in the performance appraisal documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have any evidence that your third and fourth paragraphs are true? Has your boss told you "I think you're excellent, but I never talk to anyone above me, they just have a list of who wrote which features and that's how they give the raises out?" If so, leave that company, it's insane. Your boss is repeatedly giving you assignments that will lead to never getting a raise, while telling you that you're doing fine. Your boss would also be abdicating one of the most important functions of a boss: monitoring and reviewing the all around value of every employee (including things like cultural fit, leadership, office ambience etc.)

Or, is this just how you think it works? Just a set of assumptions? Here's what I suggest you do. Ask your boss (email or in person) for a 15 minute meeting. In the meeting, say something like this:

> I know this isn't my review and I'm not asking for this meeting to be my review. You've told me many times that my work is excellent, and I'm always glad to hear that. But as the date for my review approaches, I can't shake off a worry that my raise will be based strongly (or even entirely) on the revenue I bring to the company, meaning features that are in the product. Since in my case that's none, I'm scared I'll get no raise, or a bad review. I want to avoid that.

Then wait. Let your boss tell you how reviews work in your company. You may hear any of:

- Reviews are out of my hands, I'm afraid, HR does them and you're right, it's all about features.
- Don't worry about that, I do the reviews, and if I say you're excellent, you're excellent and that's the end of that.
- I know that some people fix live bugs and some people do longterm work, and they're both of value and both considered in the reviews.
- This isn't your review meeting and I'm not discussing the way reviews work with you

That last one is highly unlikely, but I have to consider the possibility you work in an insane company.

If in fact raises are mechanically determined based on features or bug fixes in the live code, this conversation gives your boss time to adjust assignments or merge some of your code in or whatever. If, as is far more likely, things just aren't that cut and dried (after all, this is a place that paid you to write some great stuff and then left it lying around because there wasn't time to integrate it - I find it unlikely they have the tools to let someone who isn't your boss determine who wrote what and hand out raises accordingly) then you will get your reassurance.

If this chat takes less than 15 minutes, you could also offer:

> Would you like me to investigate a strategy for getting more of my code into the product, by adding tests to other people's code for a while and paying down our technical debt? Perhaps that would help our overall quality?

But in a way, that's a separate conversation, since it's not really about "hey boss, how do our reviews work anyway?" which appears to be your primary concern at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

In most (reasonably well-managed) organisations, middle management and HR will refer to your supervisor for input on your performance - so they should know about the work you've been doing.

But I have to ask - you've been hired to do a job, and you seem to have been told how your performance is to be rated - "fix things". Why are you not doing your job? Unfortunately, companies pay the piper, and so they call the tune.

On a professional level, I agree that what you're doing is right, and any sane organisation would reward your effort. But that kind of thing should be agreed (in writing, or by email) with your supervisor before spending 9 months on it. Doing this kind of thing "under the radar" is never a good idea.

Comment: Re:"before spending 9 months". Actually, while this certainly isn't the norm, it isn't uncommon that new hires are given long term tasks that have been planned as "future work" while the veterans are fighting the fires to get the code stable and customers happy. Usually, the fire fighting subsides and the new guy has a nice head start on the next product. So, I think it is worth having a talk with the supervisor about feeling that you aren't seeing how your work "fits in" to be sure it does. But I really wouldn't be overly concerned unless there are other signs that indicate you aren't wanted.

Comment: If he has been assigned that work, then he should have some kind of paper trail (or an email instructing him), and then his performance should be evaluated based on completion of the work assigned. The question reads like this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of culture. 
If you understand quality but the company does not then you will not get rewarded. 
Treat it like game with a glitch and exploit the glitch. 
Produce what they want not what is valuable. 
Yes by all means ask for the tasks they reward.

Work within your area of influence not your area of concern.
As you move up your area of influence will increase.

Comment: It appears you are for the fifth course of action. What I do like about your answer is the difference between "area of influence" and "area of concern".